# python function parameters that include symbols

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a python script as below

```
def single_value(account,key):

        file = open('%s.txt'%account)
        file.write('Hello')
        file.close()
        file2 =  open('%s.txt'%key)
        file2.write('hoiiii')
        file2.close()
single_value(accountname, 2345kwjhf53825==)
```

when I execute the script I am getting error invalid syntax. I think it is because of '==' in key. Is there is a way to define this key. 
Please help

Comment: That key appears to be a string.  As such, it needs to be enclosed in quote marks, just like all the other string constants in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The invalid syntax error is because strings must be in quotes.  Thus, replace:

```
single_value(accountname, 2345kwjhf53825==)
```

With:

```
single_value('accountname', '2345kwjhf53825==')
```

The next error is that the files are opened read-only and you want to write to them.  All together:

```
def single_value(account,key):

    with open('%s.txt'%account, 'w') as file:
        file.write('Hello')
    with open('%s.txt'%key, 'w') as file2:
        file2.write('hoiiii')

single_value('accountname', '2345kwjhf53825==')
```